# Display multiple information into my input

Tags: html, css, angularjs

**I have an input:**

```
<div class="search-field search-field-date search-field-calendar ui-datepicker-calendar columns small-3">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="goDate"
           placeholder="Date d'aller" data-mtx-datepicker data-mtx-maxdate="returnDate" data-mtx-time="horairesAller" />
</div>
```

[image]

**When I select date I have this:**

[image]

**Now I want to display multiple information like this:**

[image]

**When I select date:**

[image]

I don't know how to do this.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8WvmM9AmS8x6iArJzZv8?p=preview).

Comment: same here.. can't understand..

Comment: @Ved how can add 'DU' into the input

Comment: I think put DU in value attribute of text field.

Comment: @Ved but this input is a calendar

Comment: Create fiddle link..

Comment: Where is the Fiddle link?

Comment: @Ved in the end of the post

Comment: There is nothing on your link. I mean it is not working.You not included your controller there.

Comment: @ved sorry i update the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67117/discussion-between-mercer-and-ved).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your code and replace:

```
 $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };

With:
 $scope.dt = [];
  $scope.today = function() {
     $scope.dt[0] = 'DU:'
    $scope.dt[1] = new Date();
     $scope.dt[2] = 'JOURNEE'
  };
```

Inside HTML:

```
ng-model="dt"
```