# Bind two model names in one single input text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How can I bind two model names that are in two different scope objects into a single text box when clicked on edit button?

Here's the scope object:

```
$scope.userData= {
                  firstName:"Manoj",
                  lastName:"G"
                 }
```

In the DOM :`{{userData.firstName}} {{userData.lastName}}` will obviously print `Manoj G`.
Now,I'm having a edit button which on click shows an input text box that needs to be binded with `firstName` and `lasName`

I've tried with this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userData.firstName" required>
```

which will bind only the first

Comment: If you need to edit your firstname and lastname from one single input field, then try using `ngchange` and call a function to split with space.

Comment: Thanks @surajck.That's a good  option

Comment: Actually, that is the answer.

Comment: Just added it as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $scope.userData = [];// array as a model

        $scope.userData[0] = {firstName:"Manoj",}
        $scope.userData[1] = {lastName:"G"}

<input type="text" ng-model="userData" required>
```

I think this way you can solve your issue. I didn't checked it. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: This can't ever work. An input of type text won't take an array input.

Comment: Yes it will take. Check here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523970/display-multiple-information-into-my-input/27526696#27526696

Comment: Hi @Ved.I'm getting [object Object],[object Object] inside the text box when I try to bind

Comment: No, it will not. Check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DWQmXaaev5DFFr9XKA18?p=preview

Comment: of course you'll get [object Object], it'll try to typecast an array into a string. What do you get when you do that? Either that, or you'll get a comma-separated listing of the array elements at first, but once you write anything in your text-input, POOF!

Comment: One more thing @kumar_harsh.How can I remove comma from the input box in your plunker

Comment: @Ved can you demo in a plunker?

Comment: @MANOJ This is updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/fHO4ryohfSXufLEJ5ojo?p=preview

Comment: @surajck This is the DEMO with removed comma.: http://plnkr.co/edit/fHO4ryohfSXufLEJ5ojo?p=preview

Comment: Its not editable! When I type something, the first two charaters are going into Firstname and Lastname

Answer (score 1):

If you need to edit your firstname and lastname from one single input field, then try using `ngchange` and call a function to split with space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 seperate text fields to bind first name and lastname.
OR

You can use ng-click and add break the name into 2 parts and assign it to the scope variable